# Azure Active Directory login returns the signature key was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have implemented authentication for my ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web API using Azure AD. When I use the `[Authorize]` attribute, I am getting a http 401 error response with the message

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

My current `ConfigureService()` in `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
{
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
    {
        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
        {
            TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<mytenantid>/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
            Scopes = { { "api://<myappid>/user_impersonation", "user_impersonation" } }
        }
    }
});

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<mytenantid>/v2.0";
        o.Audience = "<myappid>";
        o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new string[] { "<myappid>", $"api://<myappid>" };
    });                

options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                 Id = "oauth"
                            },
            Scheme = "oauth2",
            Name = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});
```

Please let me know if I am missing something

Comment: You need a real id in following : new string[] { "AppId", $"api://AppId" };  "api://AppId" is just a place holder for the real id.

Comment: I am using the real id in the place of AppId.

Comment: The key is not correct.  Make sure you are using a good key.

Comment: Could you let me know which key?

Comment: You need to get the id from Azure.  Did you register for free? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/

Comment: Yes I have registered for a Microsoft developer account. I did an app registration and using the same application id and tenant id. I am testing from swagger ui. I also registered an app for swagger ui and added the client id of the swagger ui in my authorized client application.

Comment: I also see the Bearer token getting passed in the authorization header. I also pasted the token in jwt.io and found the signature is valid.

Comment: Do not know.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58589312/net-core-web-api-azure-ad-and-swagger-not-authenticating

Answer (score 0):

I have answered many similar questions before. According to your question, you  expose the web api protected by Azure. Next, you need to create a client application and use the client application to call the api application.

Usually the 401 error means that the audience of your token does not match your api. When you use the token to call the api, you will receive a 401 unauthorized error. The access token is issued based on the audience, so you must Make sure to set the `scope` to your api when you request the token. Of course you can also parse the token, check the `aud` claim, and make sure it is the api you want to call.

I use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to do a simple demonstration for you:

First expose the api of the api application and add the client application.
[image]

Next,under 'API permissions', give your front-end application access to your back-end api application:

- Under 'API permissions' click on 'Add permission', then click on the 'My APIs' tab.
- Find your backend application and select the appropriate scope.
- Click 'Add permissions'.
- Grant admin consent for your APIs.

[image]

Get token:
[image]

Parse the token：

[image]

Comment: Tried the above steps. I am able to see my API app client id in the aud field. But still no luck.

Comment: I am using the AspNet Boilerplate template. Would that be causing an issue?